# С++ код, копирующий самого себя, например, в массиве

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте. Я недавно начал изучать С++, но кое-что умею. Скажите, как писать прогу, которая копирует самого себя внутри себя, например, в массиве. Пож, помогите.

Comment: [**Вот такие дела.**][1]

[1]: http://t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRcxTmsbhgWI_1yGHyKnDQJ4_EdhnUYArxVWO3Czc3HbcinC01YykLxiEcbLw

Comment: хороший ответ, на хороший вопрос =)

Comment: да может я не так объяснил.... смотри прога должно скопировать себя то есть свой исходный текст программы внутри себя. Грубо говоря прога который размножается сам собой. Ну типа метод Куайна. надеюсь понял.

Answer (score 1):

`Quine` - это не название метода, а название такой программы. Собственно, универсального метода для составления `quine` на произвольно взятом языке, как мне известно, не существует, однако существует [**теорема**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene%27s_recursion_theorem#Application_to_quines), которая утверждает, что это возможно.

Таким образом, поиск красивых `Quine` *(особенно мультиязычных)* - это долгая и кропотливая работа.

*Вот пример такой программы для `C, C++, Ruby, Python, PHP, Perl`:*

```
 #include/*
q='''*/<stdio.h>
main(){char*_;/*=;sub _:lvalue{$_}<<q;#';<<q#'''
def printf(a,*b):print a%b,
q
#*/
_=" #include/*%cq='''*/<stdio.h>%cmain(){char*_;/*=;sub _:lvalue{%c_}<<q;#';<<q#'''%cdef printf(a,*b):print a%%b,%cq%c#*/%c_=%c%s%c;printf(_,10,10,36,10,10,10,10,34,_,34,10,10,10,10);%c#/*%cq='''*/%c}//'''#=%c";printf(_,10,10,36,10,10,10,10,34,_,34,10,10,10,10);
#/*
q='''*/
}//'''#=
```

Comment: а можешь как нибудь по своему понятию что то писать я это уже видел и как   "Вот такие дела."  .:)

Comment: @eric Как ты вообще с людьми общаешься? Я перечитал этот набор слов 10 раз и все равно ничего не смог понять.